# Logic of simple statement concerning the empty set

Tags: logic

I was curious whether the following statement is true or false.

**Question.** Let $P(x)$ be any statement pertaining to $x$.
Is "$P(x)$ for all elements $x$ of the empty set is true" a true or a false statement?

I assume it is true because it’s vacuous. Am I right? Thanks :)

Comment: A statement in the form $\forall x\in A, P(x)$ may be seen as shorthand for $\forall x, (P(x)\lor \neg(x\in A))$. For $A=\emptyset$, this becomes $\forall x,(P(x)\lor \neg (x\in\emptyset))$, which is by definition equivalent to the statement $\forall x,(P(x)\lor (\neg \perp))$ which is true.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path The statement "$P(x)$ is false $\forall x \in \emptyset$" is also true. Isn't it?

Comment: @AmanKushwaha Usually I don't work with languages where "[statement] is false" is a statement: either I prove "[statement]" or I prove "$\neg$ [statement]". So I don't know; I would assume there is a form of vacuous truth there too.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Also the negation of the original statement: "There exists an $x \in \emptyset$ such that $\neg P(x)$ is true" What about this?

Comment: @AmanKushwaha I don't work with languages where "[statement] is true" is a statement either. If my reformulation of the question doesn't answer the question... well, that's why it's a comment.

Comment: Okay @SaucyO'Path

Comment: "[P(x) for all elements x of the empty set is true]" is simply: $\forall x (x \in \emptyset \to P(x))$

Comment: That's the best answer here, @Mauro.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mauro ALLEGRANZA noted, "$P(x)$ for all elements $x$ of the empty set is true" is best translated as $\forall x(x\in\varnothing\to P(x))$, and so is true since the antecedent of the conditional is false, (hence, "trivially true").

By the way, for the question of @Aman Kushwaha, "There exists an $x\in\varnothing$ such that $\neg P(x)$ is true" could be translated as $\exists x(x\in\varnothing\wedge \neg P(x))$, and so is false since the conjunct $x\in\varnothing$ is false.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Here is a formal proof using a simplified form of natural deduction. The empty set *e* is defined on line 1. Proof by contradiction is used to obtain ~~*P*(*x*) on line 6 (screenshot from my proof checker):

[image]

Note that since, for any object $a$, the antecedent $a\in e$ is always false, we would not be able to infer that $P(a)$ is true from this result alone.